# How to set up locale in RSPEC

Tags: rspec, locale

I am new to RSPEC.  I have wrote a RSPEC code named result_spec.rb as below:

```
describe '#grouped_scores' do
subject { result.grouped_scores }

let(:result) { create(:result, user: user) }

its(:keys) { is_expected.to eq [1] }
its([1]) { is_expected.to be_within(0.001).of(6) }
end
```

Then when I wrote the method in the model named result.rb, the sample code is as below:

```
def grouped_scores
  s = 0
  if score > 10 && I18n.locale == :zh then
    s = 2
  end
  return s
end
```

However when I test RSPEC in local, I kept getting below error:

```
Failures:
1) Result#grouped_scores keys should eq [1]
 Failure/Error: its(:keys) { is_expected.to eq [1] }

   expected: [1]
        got: []

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/models/result_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
2) Result#grouped_personality_scores [1] should be within 0.001 of 6
 Failure/Error: its([1]) { is_expected.to be_within(0.001).of(6) }
   expected 0 to be within 0.001 of 6
 # ./spec/models/result_spec.rb:40:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So I was wondering, is it because I didn't setup the I18n.locale as "zh", therefore it didn't get the value? If so, how to assign locale in RSPEC? Or is there anything else I should know to debug the error in RSPEC?

Please help!  Thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean set up locale in `rspec` ? I'll share a sample of what I have understood, I could be wrong.

Comment: because in my application, I want to group the scores based on different languages.  Therefore I thought in rspec, I shall test if language is setup correctly before gathering the scores.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Testing locale

```
# Assuming I have a LocalesController with check_for_locale action
describe LocalesController do

  after(:each) do
    I18n.locale = :en
  end

  it "should check if the locale is zh" do
    get :check_for_locale, locale: :zh
    expect(I18n.locale).to eq(:zh)
  end

  it "should check if the locale is set to default that is english" do
    get :check_for_locale
    expect(I18n.locale).to eq(:en)
  end

end
```

locales_controller.rb

```
class LocalesController < ApplicationController

  def check_for_locale

  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  In the first part you use after(:each) do I18n.locale = :en end.  May I know what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: I18n is a global scope, you need to reset it before you use it again, else the previous value will still be stored. Hence, before running each scenario, I'm setting it to default that is `en`

Answer (score 3):

I come across this question while looking for response to my problem

So I have an app, for which the main language is Polish, and thus it was important for me to check all the messages in this language rather than in English. In case somebody was looking for similar thing, here is how I managed that.

In tests I've added local parameter to translation to make sure that I manually always pick the proper translation:

```
expect(subject.errors[:password].first).to eql I18n.t('errors.password.required', locale: :pl)
```

But tests were working on the default :en, so I added default locale in test environment file:

```
# config/environments/test.rb

I18n.available_locales = [:en, :pl]
config.i18n.default_locale = :pl
```

Note that after changing default locale in test environment, you no longer need to pass the :pl in your tests translations.
Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

A nicer option these days is to use [I18n.with_locale](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/i18n/I18n/Base#with_locale-instance_method) to wrap the lines you're interested in. You can couple this with rspec's `around` like this:

```
around(:each) do |example|
  I18n.with_locale(:zh) do
    example.run
  end
end
```

If you wanted to go a step further, you could probably combine it with rspec tags to tag the block (`describe`/`context`/`it`) with the locale and then use the value of the tag in the call to I18n.with_locale